# `apt update` failed on Debian Linux

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

Attempting to upgrade testing/stretch Debian Linux:

```
$ sudo apt update 
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable Release                                                                   
...
Get:25 http://mirror.vorboss.net/debian unstable/main i386 Packages 2016-03-25-1456.28.pdiff [15.0 kB]             
Fetched 686 kB in 7s (89.5 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                        
Reading package lists... Done
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_Release.gpg: The repository is insufficiently signed by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 (weak digest)
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/deb.opera.com_opera_dists_stable_InRelease: The repository is insufficiently signed by key 419D0ACF314E8E993F7F92E563F7D4AFF6D61D45 (weak digest)
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_Release, which is considered strong enough for security purposes
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What's wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, despite the last line start with `E:` (which indicates an error), `apt` didn't fail entirely; it's downloaded most of the updated package lists, it only skipped those for Opera and the Google Talk plugin. So `apt upgrade` should still offer to upgrade all the other packages.

The warnings give you some indication of what went wrong:

```
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_Release.gpg: The repository is insufficiently signed by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 (weak digest)
W: gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/deb.opera.com_opera_dists_stable_InRelease: The repository is insufficiently signed by key 419D0ACF314E8E993F7F92E563F7D4AFF6D61D45 (weak digest)
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_Release, which is considered strong enough for security purposes
```

The first two mean that the repository descriptors were signed with an old digest algorithm, which `apt` now complains about. The third is caused by [`apt`'s recent switch to SHA-256 or SHA-512 hashes only](https://tracker.debian.org/news/755358); the Talk plugin repository only provides MD5 and SHA-1 hashes, which are now ignored by `apt`.

To fix this, you can either remove the repositories for the time being, or wait for Opera and Google to fix them...

Comment: It did fail to update the repositories, and it did fail to update new security updates from Google and Opera. This move (to break SHA-1 only repositories) is Debian exercising their power to enforce security on the backs of the users by preventing them from getting security updates. Also see https://juliank.wordpress.com/2016/03/15/clarifications-and-updates-on-apt-sha1/ where it was said: "This means that it feels like SHA1 support is dropped, because sources without SHA2 won’t work; but the SHA1 signatures will still be used in addition to the SHA2 ones" ?!!? how is that not dropping sha1?